# Using the value in a row to fetch data for another column for the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geting value count from an Oracle Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239476/geting-value-count-from-an-oracle-table)

I have a simple query on 2 tables A and B

```
Table A
========
LOCATION, NAME

Table B
========
LOCATION, SKU
```

The query is:

```
select A.LOCATION, B.SKU 
  from A, B 
 where A.Location = B.Location
```

In the result of this query, I would like to add another column with the count of all locations in B which have the same SKU as returned by the above query.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on here with the answer you're looking for; for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239476/geting-value-count-from-an-oracle-table is fairly close

Comment: Hi ben...You may be right. In fact I did search across but could not find a close match myself and hence posted this question in good faith. In any case, the questions was closed and I was banned from asking more questions. This is harsh on me. Appreciate if you could upvote if you feel the question was asked in good faith.

Comment: I didn't say that you did not ask in good faith @guddo, you'll notice that I didn't vote to close the question. I've cleaned up a couple of your questions (and upvoted one) but you should essentially do what the link you received states.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben...Much appreciated....As of now I am working double hard to get my ban lifted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making the assumption here that you want A.Location, B.SKU and then the count of B.Location values that exist for B.SKU.  If that is true then it should just be a left outer join:

```
Select A.Location, B.SKU, Count(B.Location)
  from 
B Left outer join A on (B.Location = A.Location)
Where B.SKU in ( /* value */ )
group by A.Location, B.SKU
```

The only thing to note here is that for each A.Location returned for a SKU, you will see a line with that location, the SKU and the repeated count:

```
Location1, ABC, 100
Location2, ABC, 100
```

Location3, ABC, 100

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [Oracle analytical functions](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55). This allows you to add aggregate columns (such as count) without grouping the data.

So, perhaps something like this:

```
 select A.LOCATION, B.SKU, count(b.location) over (partition by sku) as locskucount
  from A, B
 where A.Location=B.Location
 order by a.location
```

This will give you a count of locations per SKU.